# Comportamiento erróneo de una evento dentro de AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un DataTable en el cuál tengo un botón que abre una ventana Modal que permite la actualización de datos. En el cual dentro de la ventana Modal hay un pequeño formulario que captura los datos del registro a editar en cada `input`.

Además, dentro del formulario hay un botón que cuándo se da clic, crea dinámicamente un `input`, que captura también los datos del registro a editar en dicho `input` generado. Y, cuando se da clic al botón por segunda vez, este `input` se elimina, y así en esa secuencia.

Cuándo cargo la página por primera vez, e inmediatamente abro la ventana modal, y dentro de él, doy clic al botón para crear el `input`, y luego doy otro para eliminarlo, no hay ningún problema.

El inconveniente se presenta cuando cierro el Modal que abrí por primera vez, y en seguida procedo a abrirlo por segunda vez, al dar clic al botón para generar el `input` dinámico, no sucede nada.

He intentado averiguar en dónde estaba la falla colocando un `alert` cada vez que se ejecuta el evento `click` del botón para ver si el evento se ejecutaba correctamente, y me doy con la sorpresa que en la segunda vez que abro la ventana Modal, al clickear en el botón, el `alert`, el evento se ejecuta 2 a 3 veces de manera automática.

Obviamente lo que quisiera es ejecutar la ventana Modal y dar clic cuantas veces quisiera sin el temor de que a la segunda o tercera vez pueda funcionar o no.

Gracias de antemano.

**Acá dejo el código:**

```
<div id="nomb_usuario" class="form-group">
            <label for="usuario">User</label>
            
    <button type="button" id="CrearInput" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"></button>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>

$(document).on('click', '.editar', function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  
  $('#usuario').remove();
       
  $.ajax({
    url :"persona/"+id+"/edit",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
      $('#nombres').val(data.resultado.nombres);
      $('#password').val(data.resultado.password);
                         
      $('#hidden_id').val(id);
      $('#action').val('Edit');
      $('#editModal').modal('show');
      
      $('#CrearInput').click(function (){
          //alert('Prueba');
        
            if($('#usuario').length == 0){

                var elementos = "<input type='text' id='usuario' name='usuario' value=''>";
                
                $('#nomb_usuario').append(elementos); 
                $('#usuario').val(data.resultado.usuario);
                                   
           }
            else {
                $('#usuario').remove();
           }
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Estás añadiendo una función al click del elemento `#CrearInput` cada vez que abres el modal, pero nunca le estás eliminando la función de click... te recomiendo que al cerrar el modal remuevas ese `$('#CrearInput').click()`, o que dejes de añadírselo de cada vez!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, justamente era eso, todo volvió a la normalidad al eliminar el evento. Ahora me entra la duda, porque se ejecutaba varias veces el evento `.click()` solo por no eliminarlo?

Comment: No me va mucho el front end pero por lo que tengo entendido, cada elemento no tiene un `click` si no que tiene un `click[]` -es decir, un array- de manera que lo que estás haciendo es añadir más y más veces esa función al evento click del elemento, y cada vez que pinchas en él, recorre el array ejecutando todos los métodos